# Custom Identity for User object in MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to get custom fields for an Identity object so that on the page side, I can simplify references to the logged-in user.

```
    WizBang.aspx

    Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.FirstName %></b>
    Your username is<%: Page.User.Identity.Name %>!
```

My other thought is to just stick it into session and set it via a `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` listener and not mess with the whole Identity in the first place. Or if there is any other way that is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` is the correct way to set a custom IIdentity. I suggest that you add a static property to your identity:

```
public MyCustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public static MyCustomIdentity Current { get { return (MyCustomIdentity) Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity; }}
}
```

And access it like `<%= MyCustomIdentity.Current.SpecialProperty %>` in your view.

Comment: How should I use my identity in that PostAuthenticate request? Just replace the current HTTPContext's? Sorry if that seems pretty obvious.